# Replace href links extensions if are local

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'd like to replace `.html` extensions with `JavaScript` for links inside a web page which not contain protocols like `http://` and `https://` to ensure they are local links.

I've tried something like this but won't work properly:

The string

```
<a href="local/path/to/url.html"> Replace me </a>
<a href="http://external.com/to/url.html"> DON'T replace me </a>
<a href="https://external.com/to/url.html"> DON'T replace me </a>
```

The regex

```
/href="^(http:|https:)(.*?).html"/gm
```

It's not clear for me how to negate protocols inside regex, if I place them nothing is matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

almost there, you just missed the negative lookahead:

```
href="(?!(?:http:|https:))(.*?).html"
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/hA4fP1/1

Answer (score 1):

The below regex would capture the local url path.

```
href="((?:(?!https?:\/\/).)+?)\.html"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/38)

Answer (score 0):

```
(href="(?!http)[^>]*\/.*?)\.html
```

Try this.replace with `$1Javascript`.see demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/39